# How to upload a pdf from iPhone

Tags: iphone, pdf

I want to upload a pdf to an app. It’s a certificate for COVID but I do not see option to upload it from Files or iCloud.
The other app where I can download only provide pdf and saving options are either in Files and “on my iPhone” which I do not know how to browse.

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can take a screenshot of the PDF file (assuming it is just one page) after opening the PDF file. The screenshot will be saved to your Photo Library. You can then upload the screenshot in your Photo Library to the app.

See the directions in [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289) if you need help on taking a screenshot on your iPhone.

Comment: The problem is the site where I am uploading it only certain aspect ratio so my name is cut off.

Comment: Not absolutely sure if this would help but have you tried cropping and resizing the picture of the document using the editing tools in the iPhone’s Photos app?